# How to properly display some highlight subgraphs?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, annotationvalue

My graph is as follows.

```
g=Graph[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12},
{UndirectedEdge[1, 2], UndirectedEdge[1, 3], UndirectedEdge[1, 4], UndirectedEdge[2, 5], 
UndirectedEdge[4, 5], UndirectedEdge[2, 6], UndirectedEdge[2, 7], UndirectedEdge[2, 8], 
UndirectedEdge[3, 8], UndirectedEdge[3, 9], UndirectedEdge[4, 9], UndirectedEdge[5, 10], 
UndirectedEdge[6, 10], UndirectedEdge[9, 10], UndirectedEdge[6, 11], UndirectedEdge[7, 11],
UndirectedEdge[9, 11], UndirectedEdge[7, 12], UndirectedEdge[8, 12], UndirectedEdge[9, 12],
UndirectedEdge[1, 8], UndirectedEdge[2, 3], UndirectedEdge[1, 9], UndirectedEdge[3, 4], 
UndirectedEdge[1, 5], UndirectedEdge[4, 2], UndirectedEdge[2, 10],UndirectedEdge[5, 6], 
UndirectedEdge[2, 11], UndirectedEdge[6, 7], UndirectedEdge[2, 12], UndirectedEdge[7, 8], 
UndirectedEdge[3, 12], UndirectedEdge[8, 9], UndirectedEdge[4, 10], UndirectedEdge[9, 5], 
UndirectedEdge[6, 9], UndirectedEdge[10, 11], UndirectedEdge[7, 9], UndirectedEdge[11, 12]}, 
{EdgeShapeFunction -> {UndirectedEdge[1, 8] -> {"CurvedEdge", "Curvature" -> 3}, 
UndirectedEdge[2, 3] -> {"CurvedEdge", "Curvature" -> 3}}, FormatType -> TraditionalForm, 
GraphHighlight -> {UndirectedEdge[2, 3], UndirectedEdge[2, 10], UndirectedEdge[1, 5], 
UndirectedEdge[8, 9],UndirectedEdge[2, 12], UndirectedEdge[3, 12], UndirectedEdge[2, 11], 
UndirectedEdge[11, 12],UndirectedEdge[1, 8], UndirectedEdge[4, 2], UndirectedEdge[5, 6],
UndirectedEdge[9, 5], UndirectedEdge[1, 9], UndirectedEdge[6, 7], UndirectedEdge[7, 8], UndirectedEdge[6, 9], 
UndirectedEdge[10, 11], UndirectedEdge[7, 9], UndirectedEdge[3, 4], UndirectedEdge[4, 10]}, 
GraphHighlightStyle -> {UndirectedEdge[7, 8] -> {EdgeStyle -> {{{Dashing[{Small, Small}], 
GrayLevel[0], AbsoluteThickness[1]}}}}, UndirectedEdge[5, 6] -> {EdgeStyle -> {{{Dashing[{Small, Small}],
GrayLevel[0], AbsoluteThickness[1]}}}},UndirectedEdge[8, 9] -> {EdgeStyle -> {{{Dashing[{Small, Small}], 
GrayLevel[0], AbsoluteThickness[1]}}}}, UndirectedEdge[6, 9] -> {EdgeStyle -> {{{Dashing[{Small, Small}], 
GrayLevel[0], AbsoluteThickness[1]}}}}, UndirectedEdge[1, 8] -> {EdgeStyle -> {{{Dashing[{Small, Small}], 
GrayLevel[0], AbsoluteThickness[1]}}}}, UndirectedEdge[4, 10] -> {EdgeStyle -> {{{Dashing[{Small, Small}],
GrayLevel[0], AbsoluteThickness[1]}}}},UndirectedEdge[2, 11] -> {EdgeStyle -> {{{Dashing[{Small, Small}], 
GrayLevel[0], AbsoluteThickness[1]}}}}, UndirectedEdge[2, 12] -> {EdgeStyle -> {{{Dashing[{Small, Small}], 
GrayLevel[0], AbsoluteThickness[1]}}}}, 
UndirectedEdge[7, 9] -> {EdgeStyle -> {{{Dashing[{Small, Small}], GrayLevel[0], AbsoluteThickness[1]}}}}, 
UndirectedEdge[4, 2] -> {EdgeStyle -> {{{Dashing[{Small, Small}], GrayLevel[0], AbsoluteThickness[1]}}}},
UndirectedEdge[3, 12] -> {EdgeStyle -> {{{Dashing[{Small, Small}],
GrayLevel[0], AbsoluteThickness[1]}}}}, UndirectedEdge[2, 3] -> {EdgeStyle -> {{{Dashing[{Small, Small}], 
GrayLevel[0], AbsoluteThickness[1]}}}}, 
UndirectedEdge[11, 12] -> {EdgeStyle -> {{{Dashing[{Small,Small}], GrayLevel[0], AbsoluteThickness[1]}}}}, 
UndirectedEdge[1, 5] -> {EdgeStyle -> {{{Dashing[{Small, Small}], GrayLevel[0], AbsoluteThickness[1]}}}}, 
UndirectedEdge[3, 4] -> {EdgeStyle -> {{{Dashing[{Small, Small}], GrayLevel[0], 
AbsoluteThickness[1]}}}}, UndirectedEdge[1, 9] -> {EdgeStyle -> {{{Dashing[{Small, Small}], 
GrayLevel[0], AbsoluteThickness[1]}}}}, UndirectedEdge[6, 7] -> {EdgeStyle -> {{{Dashing[{Small, Small}], GrayLevel[0], 
AbsoluteThickness[1]}}}}, UndirectedEdge[10, 11] -> {EdgeStyle -> {{{Dashing[{Small, Small}], 
GrayLevel[0], AbsoluteThickness[1]}}}}, UndirectedEdge[2, 10] -> {EdgeStyle -> {{{Dashing[{Small, 
Small}], GrayLevel[0], AbsoluteThickness[1]}}}}, UndirectedEdge[9, 5] -> {EdgeStyle -> 
{{{Dashing[{Small, Small}], GrayLevel[0], AbsoluteThickness[1]}}}}},GraphLayout -> "TutteEmbedding",
ImageSize -> {871.8329670329658, Automatic}, PlotRange -> 2, VertexCoordinates -> {{-1.8369701987210297*^-16, 1.}, 
{1., 1.2246467991473532*^-16}, {-1., -2.4492935982947064*^-16}, {0.17983821157707894, 0.380956302850689}, {0.5179703755811089, 
0.14286048039806887}, {0.5827152767774986, 4.06048298747889*^-6}, {0.517970375581109, -0.1428538053162018}, 
{6.123233995736766*^-17, -1.}, {0.02156445069733078, 4.005049120137105*^-6}, 
{0.37408336768531275, 0.04762284864339216}, {0.3740833676853128, -0.04761524659469806}, {0.17984494209281332, -0.38094993342236055}}}]
```

[image]

I wanted to search for all subgraphs of `g` isomorphic to  $K_{3,3}$. So I called the function `IGLADFindSubisomorphisms` inside the IGraphM package.

```
Needs["IGraphM`"]
HighlightGraph[g, Subgraph[g, #], GraphHighlightStyle -> "Thick"] & /@
  Union[Sort@*Values /@ 
   IGLADFindSubisomorphisms[CompleteGraph[{3, 3}], g]]
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

But in many drawn graphs, some edges of a subgraph $K_{3,3}$ that **should be highlighted in red are not marked**. I guess it's a property modification problem. When I remove all properties of `g`, all the subgraphs $K_{3,3}$'s are remark red and thick correctly.

```
g1 = AnnotationDelete[g]
HighlightGraph[g1, Subgraph[g1, #], GraphHighlightStyle -> "Thick"] & /@ 
 Union[Sort@*Values /@ 
   IGLADFindSubisomorphisms[CompleteGraph[{3, 3}], g1]]
```

[image]
[image]

I would like to ask how to **display these subgraphs** well **without deleting the attributes of the graph** `g`. Because by removing the attributes, the layout of the graph `g` is disrupted and not conducive to observation.

---

**Edits (Very surprised):** I just noticed that even in the graph with the attributes removed, it did not show  subgraph $K_{3,3}$ that I wanted. For example, the degree of $v$ in the figure above is $4$ in the red subgraph, not $3$?!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set custom Style for HighlightGraph:

```
Multicolumn[
 HighlightGraph[g, Style[#, Thick, Red, EdgeForm[{Red, Thick}]], 
    ImageSize -> 200] & /@ 
  FindIsomorphicSubgraph[g, CompleteGraph[{3, 3}], All], 4]
```

[image]

Comment: `FindIsomorphicSubgraph` does not find all subgraphs. Please see my answer.

Comment: @Szabolcs it's fixed in the upcoming version

Answer (score 3):

> **Edits (Very surprised):** I just noticed that even in the graph with the attributes removed, it did not show  subgraph $K_{3,3}$ that I wanted. For example, the degree of $v$ in the figure above is $4$ in the red subgraph, not $3$?!

This is because you are highlighting subgraphs that are *induced* by certain vertex sets. There is no *induced* $K_{3,3}$ in your graph:

```
In[52]:= sg = CompleteGraph[{3, 3}];

In[53]:= IGLADFindSubisomorphisms[sg, g, "Induced" -> True]
Out[53]= {}
```

This is how you highlight all not-necessarily-induced matches:

```
In[56]:= subgraphs = DeleteDuplicatesBy[
   EdgeList[sg] /. IGLADFindSubisomorphisms[sg, g],
   Sort[Sort /@ #] & (* canonicalize undirected edge set, assuming no tagged edges *)
 ];

In[57]:= Length[subgraphs]
Out[57]= 40

In[58]:= 
HighlightGraph[g, Graph[#], GraphHighlightStyle -> "Thick"] & /@ 
 Take[subgraphs, 4]
```

[image]

Notice the difference between `Graph[subgraphs[[1]]]` and `Subgraph[g, VertexList[subgraphs[[1]]]]`.

It's also good to point out that some of these subgraphs have the same vertices, but different edges. We can get these groups of subgraphs as follows:

```
Select[GroupBy[subgraphs, Sort@*VertexList], Length[#] > 1 &]
```

Let's visualize the first group:

```
HighlightGraph[g, Graph[#], GraphHighlightStyle -> "Thick"] & /@ 
 SelectFirst[GroupBy[subgraphs, Sort@*VertexList], Length[#] > 1 &]
```

[image]

As you point out in the comments, the built-in [`FindIsomorphicSubgraph`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindIsomorphicSubgraph.html) appears to miss these, and seems to consider all subgraphs with the same vertex set as identical, even though this is not the case. This must be the reason why it finds only 30:

```
In[78]:= Length@FindIsomorphicSubgraph[g, sg, All]
Out[78]= 30
```

As you show in your question, we'd get 30 results if we'd filter this way:

```
In[80]:= Length@DeleteDuplicatesBy[IGLADFindSubisomorphisms[sg, g], Sort@*Values]
Out[80]= 30
```

**I think you are right and `FindIsomorphicSubgraph` is buggy.** However, `FindSubgraphIsomorphism` appears to work correctly. All of the following find the same number of subisomorphisms:

```
In[82]:= 
Length@#[sg, g] & /@ {IGLADFindSubisomorphisms,IGVF2FindSubisomorphisms, FindSubgraphIsomorphism[##, All] &}

Out[82]= {2880, 2880, 2880}
```

---

##### On the `FindIsomorphicSubgraph` bug

An obvious way to demonstrate the bug in `FindIsomorphicSubgraph` is `FindIsomorphicSubgraph[CompleteGraph[4], CycleGraph[4], All]`, which returns a single result, even though there are clearly more. `FindCycle[CompleteGraph[4], {4}, All]` returns three distinct results. I reported this to WRI.

Comment: Thank you very much. I see. But I have another question. You get 80 $K_{3,3}$s, but the built-in function  `FindIsomorphicSubgraph[g, CompleteGraph[{3, 3}], All]` gets 30. Is the built-in function not searching enough?

Comment: @licheng I think you're right and `FindIsomorphicSubgraph` is buggy. I updated the answer. I was also filtering duplicates incorrectly. There are only 40, not 80. I did not canonicalize undirected edges.